# How to rebuild on resource file change in cmake?

Tags: build, cmake, resources, shader

I have some shader files inside of a resource directory 'Shaders'. I want my app to copy this folder to the runtime directory everytime there are changes inside of one file in it before the build. How can I achieve this?

Right now I use this here:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET my_app PRE_BUILD
        COMMAND rm ARGS -rf ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders
        COMMAND cp ARGS -a ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_app/Viewer/Shaders ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        )
```

But this does only work when I change another file so a built is needed, not the shader files themselves. What can I do?

Comment: suggestion to remove `shader` tag as this not related to shaders

Answer (score 0):

What I know figured out to be working is this here:

```
file(GLOB shaders "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/my_app/Viewer/Shaders/*")
message(status Copy shaders)
foreach(shader ${shaders})
    message(status "From ${shader}")
    get_filename_component(outputFileName ${shader} NAME)
    message(status "To ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders/${outputFileName}")
    configure_file(${shader} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Shaders/${outputFileName} COPYONLY)
endforeach()
```