# Recompile CMake library for every main file (and consider #define)

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a Websockets library for C++. My project has the library folder and a `tests` folder.

The `tests` folder contains many source files that each is compiled as a stand-alone executable and considered a test. The relevant CMakeLists for it looks like this:

```
file(GLOB TEST_SOURCES "src/*.cpp")
foreach(file ${TEST_SOURCES})
  get_filename_component(_F_NAME ${file} NAME_WE)
  add_executable(${_F_NAME} ${file})
  target_link_libraries (${_F_NAME} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
  target_link_libraries(${_F_NAME} tiny_websockets_lib Catch)
  if(WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(${_F_NAME} wsock32 ws2_32)
  endif()
  add_test(NAME ${_F_NAME} COMMAND ${_F_NAME})
endforeach()
```

Basically for every cpp file in `src/` I create a new executable and link to it my library (here called `tiny_websockets_lib`).

The libraries' CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE tinyws_SOURCES
    "src/*.cpp"
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE tinyws_HEADERS 
    "include/*.h"
    "include/*.hpp"
)

include_directories(include/tiny_websockets)
add_library(tiny_websockets_lib STATIC ${tinyws_HEADERS} ${tinyws_SOURCES})
set_target_properties(tiny_websockets_lib PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_include_directories(tiny_websockets_lib PUBLIC include)
```

**The Issue:**
In the library I have some conditional compilation flags. For example, this flag:

```cpp
#define _WS_CONFIG_NO_TRUE_RANDOMNESS
```

can be defined and it will change the behivour of the library.

The problem is that the library **only compiles once**, so if my test looks like this:

```cpp
#define _WS_CONFIG_NO_TRUE_RANDOMNESS
#include <library_stuff_with_conditional_compile_ifdefs>

int main() {
  // tests
}
```

The library will not be compiled again, and the flag will not be considered.

**TLDR:** To my understanding the library is compiled once and linked multiple times. I would like the library to recompile and consider the main file for every tests.

You can see the actual project and structure here: https://github.com/gilmaimon/TinyWebsockets

Thank You.

Comment: you need to track this file changes library_stuff_with_conditional_compile_ifdefs for reference you can try this (not same but similar may give you idea) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37237469/how-to-rebuild-on-resource-file-change-in-cmake

Comment: @Abdurrahim thank you for your comment. I don't think the change tracking is the issue. When i clear the build and only make the specific test (that has the #defines) the result is the same. It just finishes building the library before even looking at the main file (thats what it feels like to me).

Comment: Found something I am giving it a go as a weekend exercise https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-build-multiple-modes-without-switching- i forked your repo and trying to implement it where I will be building multiple targets and build test for each target accordingly will see if it works out

Comment: @Abdurrahim cool, thank you! I will watch for your commits on the fork and will also update if I'll manage to do it by my own. Thanks!